# How Do I Call 7zip From Gradle To Unsign A Jar

Tags: gradle

I want to batch Unsign some jars with in gradle but I don't want to use the [ant jar method](https://gist.github.com/jarek-przygodzki/4981074) as it is too slow.

Using the 7zip command line is much faster:

```
7z.exe d activemq-pool-5.7.0.jar META-INF/SIGFILE.*
```

Where SIGFILE is the name of the previous signature.

I am trying to do it in gradle like this

```
    println "Unsigning jars"
    file(unsignedFolder + "/jars").listFiles().each { File file ->
        exec {
            workingDir '../tools'
            commandLine '7z.exe', 'd', file.absolutePath, 'META-INF/SIGFILE.*'              
        }
    }
```

However, I get the error:

```
Starting process 'command '7z.exe''. Working directory: D:\code\project\tools Command: 7z.exe d D:\code\project\build\unsigned\jars\activemq-pool-5.7.0.jar META-INF/SIGFILE.*
:signWebstart FAILED
:signWebstart (Thread[Daemon,5,main]) completed. Took 0.109 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unsignJars'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '7z.exe''
```

Comment: Shouldn't be win command started with `cmd /c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28997703/1000011) I realised what it should be.

I am using the command line version of 7zip now - 7za. There is also a unix version at http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/ so I am packaging them both with my script and using something along the lines of the following:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

task unSignJars() {
  if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    println "*** WINDOWS "
    exec {
        executable "7za.exe"
        args "d", "temp.jar", "META-INF/SIGN.RSA"
    }
  } else if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_UNIX)) {
    println "*** UNIX "
    exec {
        executable "7za"
        args "d", "temp.jar", "META-INF/SIGN.RSA"
    }
  } else {
    println "*** NOT SUPPORTED "
  }
}
```

This method is twice as fast as using Java nio http://thinktibits.blogspot.ca/2013/02/Delete-Files-From-ZIP-Archive-Java-Example.html which in itself is twice as fast as the ant method mention in the OP.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
public class ZPFSDelete {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

        /* Define ZIP File System Properies in HashMap */    
        Map<String, String> zip_properties = new HashMap<>(); 
        /* We want to read an existing ZIP File, so we set this to False */
        zip_properties.put("create", "false"); 

        /* Specify the path to the ZIP File that you want to read as a File System */
        URI zip_disk = URI.create("jar:file:/my_zip_file.zip");

        /* Create ZIP file System */
        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip_disk, zip_properties)) {
            /* Get the Path inside ZIP File to delete the ZIP Entry */
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("source.sql");
            System.out.println("About to delete an entry from ZIP File" + pathInZipfile.toUri() ); 
            /* Execute Delete */
            Files.delete(pathInZipfile);
            System.out.println("File successfully deleted");   
        } 
    }
}
```

However, unix zip -d is twice as fast again but it isn't portable.