# How Do I Remove A File From An Archive Using Gradle

Tags: gradle

In Unix I can do the following to delete a file from my jar

```
zip -d myfile.jar META-INF/SIGN.RSA
```

Is there a simple way to do it in Gradle/Groovy?

I don't want to unzip and re-zip the whole file as I have some very large jars.

As you can probably tell I am un-signing some jars before re-signing them with my own. If you have a solution for that (and doesn't require unpacking and repacking) I'll accept your answer too.

Comment: Is the file `META-INF/SIGN.RSA` located somewhere in the sources, or maybe it's generated?

Comment: It is an example of a file that is generated when you sign a jar. I want to unsign the jar and resign it with my own cert in the most efficient way possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per my knowledge there's no built-in task for this specific case.
However, you can easily do it by using [exec](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html), e.g.:

```
exec {
    executable "jar.exe"
    args "-d", "myfile.jar", "META-INF/SIGN.RSA"
}
```

Comment: jar.exe doesn't have a -d option.

Comment: I realised I asked a similar question 3 months ago! 7zip seems to be the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072183/how-do-i-call-7zip-from-gradle-to-unsign-a-jar

Comment: @opticyclic jar.exe does have a `-d` option, but it means *-d, --describe-module      Print the module descriptor, or automatic module name*. Also, if it did not help then why did you accept this answer?